# Checked style not applying

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Good afternoon,

I have an MVC4 application....

can anyone please let me know why this is not applying the style to the text within the span straight after the checkbox...

When the checkbox is checked

```
 @Html.LabelFor(mod => mod.rememberMe)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(mod => mod.rememberMe)
                <span id="mynum">Example Span to change colour</span>
```

Now the styles applied to this are:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{ height: 20px;width: 20px;}

    input[type="checkbox"]:checked > span {
        color: blue;
    }
```

I would expect that when the checkbox is checked...the span straight after the checkbox, it's text would turn green....can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advanced....

Comment: `>` means "immediate parent". You want `+` which means "immediate sibling".

Comment: Does it, I thought > meant child of, no matter how nested.... and + means the direct child of...

Comment: Well, the first thing I would say is "give it a try" :)  If you have no intervening symbols (say `h1 div`) than that means "child at any level". But `>` means "immediate child". See here for more: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the way that MVC writes the HTML...it puts extra hidden elements in the output...I solved this by using the general sibling combinator

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span {
    color: blue;
}
```